# What happens when converting char * to string *?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```cpp
char * ss = "abscd";
string * b = (string *) ss;
std::cout << ss << std::endl;
std::cout << *b << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
abscd
//empty line
```

I thought it would be :

```
abscd
abscd
```

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, because `std::string` and `char *` are unrelated types.

Comment: You can *construct* a string like `std::string b{ss};` but you should not *cast* a char* to a string* as they are completely unrelated types

Comment: C++ `static_cast` would report an error during compile time. https://godbolt.org/z/c95xq8

Comment: `(string *)` is a c-style cast. It usually greatly improves code quality if you avoid those in general.

Comment: Have a look at [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as well.

Comment: You can convert a `char*` to a `std::string` (which actually creates a new string which looks the same as the original), but you can't convert a `char*` to a `std::string*` (which would just say "this thing that you think is a `char` is actually a `std::string`"). These are different kinds of conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have misunderstood something. First of all you miss a `const` here:

```
const char * ss = "abscd";
```

Next, `std::string` is meant to replace c-strings, like the one you have with `ss`. However, `std::string` is a string, while `std::string*` is a pointer to a string. As `std::string` is not related to `char` as far as conversions between pointers are concerned, your code has undefined behavior.

To create a `std::string` from a c-string use its constructor, eg like this:

```
std::string b{ss};
```

Last but not least, avoid c-style casts like this one `string * b = (string *) ss;`. You can cast anything to anything without getting a compiler error, but that does not mean that it is correct.