# How to store the address that a pointer points to to another pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

This code aims to make pointer c points to the address that pointer a points to.
I can't understand this expression: " char* c= (char*)&a ".
Can someone please clarify it?

```
string* a =new string;
std::cin >> *a;
char* c= (char*)&a;
delete a;
```

Comment: The expression makes little sense. Do you mean `const char* c = a->c_str();`?

Comment: After `a`'s deletion you can't use address stored in `c`

Comment: `char* c= (char*)&a;` looks like a big mistake. With a C-cast you can "sell" nearly everything to the compiler (to make it silent) but finally you still get U.B. (sooner or later). (And, without compiler complaints, it will become even harder to find it.)

Comment: different question, similar misunderstanding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66027913/4117728

Comment: The address a pointer points to is its value, not its address. To get the address the pointer `a` points to you can simply read `a`, not `&a`. To store the address the pointer `a` points to in `c` you would `char *c = (char *)a;` but that doesn't make much sense. Please describe what you expect or what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: I'm trying to make c point to the memory address of the first letter in string *a. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

> How to store the address that a pointer points to to another pointer?

You can copy it:

```
T* a = some_address;
T* b = a; // copied the address from a to b
```

---

> I can't understand this expression: `char* c= (char*)&a`

This declares a variable of type `char*` which is a pointer to `char`. The name of the variable is `c`. The variable is initialised with the expression `(char*)&a`.

The unary `&` is the addressof operator. When applied to an lvalue, it results in the address of the object named by the lvalue. In this case, you get the address of the variable `a`. Note that the address of the variable `a` is not the same as the address of dynamic object that `a` points to. Since the type of `a` is `string*`, the type of the pointer to `a` is `string**`.

`(char*)a` is an explicit conversion (aka C-style cast). In this case it performs a reinterpret cast from `string**` to `char*`. Without context, this conversion seems to make no sense, but it makes the example well-formed regardless. Don't use C-style casts in C++.

P.S. Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation. If `string` is `std::string`, then there is hardly ever a reason to allocate it dynamically.

---

> I'm trying to make c point to the memory address of the first letter in string *a. How do I do that?

There are no letters in `a` at all. `a` simply contains the address of a `string` object.

If you want to point to the first character that is stored in the buffer managed by the string that is pointed by `a` - with the assumption that `string` is `std::string`, then you can indirect through `a` and use the `data` member function of `std::string`:

```
char* c = a->data();
```

Comment: well-formed because it is a pointer to `char`, while situation would be different with a `int*`, no?. Maybe clarify that

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The cast would still be well-formed. Attempting to access the memory through the reinterpreted pointer would be UB in that case though.

Comment: oh right. I don't know what were OPs intention, but if they wanted to get a pointer to a c-string, they are on the wrong track. You already explain that, I just wasnt sure if the "well-formed" can cause a misunderstanding. Nevermind, you already had my vote

Comment: I'm trying to make c point to the memory address of the first letter in string *a. How do I do that?